# Pegar os atributos de um objeto Thread?

Tags: java

É possível pegar os atributos de um objeto Thread? pois estou utilizado threads para ler varios arquivos(um por thread) (que possui numeros float separados por \n) armazenar os floats fazer a soma dos floats e fazer a media de valores, porem é necessário fazer uma soma geral dos arquivos porem não consigo pegar os valores gerados dentro da thread pela classe principal.

classe principal:

```
package multithread;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MultiThread {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> pathsCemMil = new ArrayList<String>();
    pathsCemMil.add("C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MultiThread\\src\\arquivos\\NumerosFloatCemMil_A.txt");
    pathsCemMil.add("C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MultiThread\\src\\arquivos\\NumerosFloatCemMil_B.txt");
    pathsCemMil.add("C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MultiThread\\src\\arquivos\\NumerosFloatCemMil_C.txt");

    List<String> pathsDezMil = new ArrayList<String>();
    pathsDezMil.add("C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MultiThread\\src\\arquivos\\NumerosFloatDezMil_A.txt");
    pathsDezMil.add("C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MultiThread\\src\\arquivos\\NumerosFloatDezMil_B.txt");
    pathsDezMil.add("C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MultiThread\\src\\arquivos\\NumerosFloatDezMil_C.txt");

    List<String> pathsUmMilhao = new ArrayList<String>();
    pathsUmMilhao.add("C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MultiThread\\src\\arquivos\\NumerosFloatUmMilhao_A.txt");
    pathsUmMilhao.add("C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MultiThread\\src\\arquivos\\NumerosFloatUmMilhao_B.txt");
    pathsUmMilhao.add("C:\\Users\\Ricardo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MultiThread\\src\\arquivos\\NumerosFloatUmMilhao_C.txt");

    List<Thread> threadsDezMil = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for(String path : pathsDezMil){
        threadsDezMil.add(new Worker(path));

    }

    List<Thread> threadsCemMil = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for(String path : pathsCemMil){
        new Worker(path).start();
    }

    List<Thread> threadsUmMilhao = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for(String path : pathsUmMilhao){
        new Worker(path).start();
    }
}

}
```

Classe thread:

```
package multithread;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Worker extends Thread{
String path;
double valoresSoma;
double valoresMedia;
int valoresAcimaMedia;

public Worker(String path){
    this.path = path;
}

public void run(){
    try {
        List<Double> valores = new ArrayList<Double>();
        valores = reader(this.path);
        valoresSoma = soma(valores);
        valoresMedia = media(valoresSoma,valores.size());
        valoresAcimaMedia = acimaMedia(valores, valoresMedia);
        System.out.println(this.path);
        System.out.println(valores.size());
        System.out.println(valoresSoma);
        System.out.println(valoresMedia);
        System.out.println(valoresAcimaMedia);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Worker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
public static List<Double> reader(String path) throws IOException{
    List<Double> valores = new ArrayList<>();
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String data = null;
    while((data = reader.readLine()) != null){
        valores.add(Double.parseDouble(data)); 
    }
    fileReader.close();
    reader.close();
    return valores;
}

public static double soma(List<Double> valores){
    double soma = 0;
    for(Double valor : valores){
        soma += valor;
    }
    return soma;
}

public static double media(double soma, int qtde){
    return soma/qtde;
}

public static int acimaMedia(List<Double> valores, double media){
    int qtde = 0;
    for(Double valor : valores){
        if(valor > media){
            qtde++;
        }
    }
    return qtde;
}
}
```

Exemplo de arquivo que possui os valores float:

```
898.29
653.46
572.77
669.53
695.89
400.91
392.73
547.55
748.77
38.43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível recuperar informações dos objetos normalmente, porém você precisa esperar as *threads* finalizarem a execução antes de tentar fazer isso.

Se quiser fazer na mão, use os comandos de sincronização básicos do Java `wait` e `notify`.

Entretanto, exista uma API muito mais fácil para trabalhar com threads e sincronização, o `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Veja o exemplo simples que fiz:

## Thread

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

    int soma;

    public void run() {
        //executa operações complexas
        soma = new Random().nextInt();
    }

    public int getSoma() {
        return soma;
    }

}
```

## Código gerenciador

```
//cria pool de threads para execução de tarefas
ThreadPoolExecutor p = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 10, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10));

//cria threads com tarefas a executar
Worker w1 = new Worker(); 
Worker w2 = new Worker(); 
Worker w3 = new Worker();

//submete tarefas para a execução
p.submit(w1);
p.submit(w2);
p.submit(w3);

//força a execução e finalização das threads
p.shutdown();

//aguarda finalização das threads em execução
p.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

//recupera resultados parciais e exibe
int soma = w1.getSoma() + w2.getSoma() + w3.getSoma();
System.out.println("Soma = " + soma);
```